# Incomplete border around range in excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm using Vb.Net to automate an excel spreadsheet generation. I'm drawing a border around a range, but for some reason the text in the first columns hides the border. Is there some way of sending this text to "background", like a z-index in web, so that the border displays correctly?

[image: Spreadsheet capture with wrong border]

This is the relevant line of code:

```
range = sheet.Range("B" + (sectionStart).ToString, "M" + (currentLine).ToString)
            range.BorderAround(XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, XlBorderWeight.xlThin)
```

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for your comment. I can't make A wider, in fact later on in my code I'm setting it to have a white font, because the data in this column is not to be used by humans, but for computing data. Also, the value for column B is already an empty string "".

Comment: @pnuts I tried your suggestion with the same results..

Comment: Why not hide column A altogether. Alternatively if possible input an empty space into column B where there are corresponding values in the same row in A e.g. input empty space in B88:B91

Comment: @pnuts Yes, i set it to 1 without results.

Comment: @pnuts I posted an image with the problem: the border didn't draw around the whole range. The problematic region is remarked in red.

Comment: @pnuts The problem seems to be caused by the empty rows in column B. Placing some text or an empty string in the column "solve" the problem. Is like data in column A besides the empty row haves a higher "z-index" if column B is empty by some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your best bet is to wrap the text in column A, we get this problem a lot here at work and it usually solves the issue.

Try adding:

```
sheet.Range(“A:A″).IsWrapText = True
```

To your code, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but it doesn't show the border after applying your code. In fact, it's just breaking the sheet design, as it's making the rows much wider :-(

Comment: hmm, this always works for me. Possibly @pnuts idea of putting a space in column B would be the way to go, that way excel thinks there is something there (unlike an empty string)

Comment: I'm very confused about this, as the same code is working fine in previous rows as you can see in the image. :-(

Comment: but all of the other rows in column A do have data entered in the respective cell in column B

Comment: That's the key! If a place an empty space in B column then the border shows up! It's not elegant, but at least it works! Thank you very much.